# Javascript formatting broken in visual studio 2008

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I do not have a listing for JScript in my studio options under Text Editor.
Thus my studio will not format javascript for me when i type a semicolon.
This is a new machine for me. My old machine has this listing.
I have uninstalled and reinstalled studio 3 times with no luck

Answer (score 0):

you need sp1 for vs2008.

Answer (score 0):

If code has some syntactic errors formatting will not work.

Sometimes even if the code is good VS have problems with formatting, in those situations I usually copypaste whole code to "unblock" formatting.

Remember that the file must have ".js" extension.

Make sure that you have selected desired options in "Tools -> Options... -> Text Editor -> JScript -> Formatting".